# Converting raster data from netcdf to image

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, netcdf

I'm rasterizing some wind data from [oos.soest.hawaii.edu/erddap/griddap/NCEP_Global_Best](http://oos.soest.hawaii.edu/erddap/griddap/NCEP_Global_Best) to use as an overlay of a final image, but I'm having issues calculating the bounding box of the final image.

Can I safely assume, giving the data is continuous, that each latitude/longitude corresponds to the center of my final pixel? If not, which metadata keys should I have been looking?

In the case that the position is indeed referencing the center of the pixel, then can I say the following?

```
bounding_south = smallest_latitude - (latitude_resolution / 2)
bounding_north = largest_latitude + (latitude_resolution / 2)

bounding_west = smallest_longitude - (latitude_resolution / 2)
bounding_east = largest_longitude + (latitude_resolution / 2)
```

Unfortunately I couldn't access the data using gdal_translate to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing an `ncdump` on the data from one of the soest files gives this chunk of metadata for the precipitation flux variable:

```
    double pratesfc(time, latitude, longitude) ;
            pratesfc:_FillValue = -999000000. ;
            pratesfc:colorBarMaximum = 0.005f ;
            pratesfc:colorBarMinimum = 0.f ;
            pratesfc:coordinates = "time_run time latitude longitude" ;
            pratesfc:ioos_category = "Meteorology" ;
            pratesfc:long_name = "rainfall rate" ;
            pratesfc:missing_value = -999000000. ;
            pratesfc:standard_name = "precipitation_flux" ;
            pratesfc:units = "kg m-2 s-1" ;
```

The data in netcdf files should correspond exactly to the coordinate points in the file.  If you are representing pixels as little squares, (contrary to [A Pixel Is Not A Little Square](https://www.google.com/search?q=pixel%20is%20not%20a%20little%20square%20%22A%20Pixel%20is%20Not%20a%20Little%20Square%22%20theory)) then each of the data points is a 1-pixel area in the raster, then it would be center-pixel data, and the pixel edges would be +/- resolution/2. wider than the coordinates in the netcdf file.